# Excel: How to auto-populate cell with data using static column with a row dependent on another cell?

Tags: ios, vba, excel

I've got an spreadsheet with hundreds of problems listed out that map to a smaller number of solutions. I want to use this data to generate a drop down that selects the problem from a data range, and then next to it, another cell that populates the solution from one row over.

Example:

```
Column A    Column B
Issue 1     Solution 1
Issue 2     Solution 4
Issue 3     Solution 5
Issue 4     Solution 1
Issue 5     Solution 1
Issue 6     Solution 3
Issue 7     Solution 2
```

If I want to create two cells where the first one is a drop down list (A1:A7), how can I make the second cell populate using a static column (B), but with a dynamic row number based off the first cell. So if someone chooses Issue 6 from the dropdown (A6) the second cell will know to populate Solution 3 (B6)?

Thnaks

Comment: Use the **INDEX()** worksheet function.........see Excel Help.

Answer (score 0):

To do this, you need two steps:

1) For the first cell where you'll have the dropdown option, click on Data Validation command (under the Data ) In the Settings menu in the dialogue box, click on "list" and set the Source to the Column A cells (without the header). This will make these the options in the drop down menu

[image: Here's the data validation dialogue box]

2) For the second cell where you'll have the solution automatically change depending on the first cell, you'll need to use the vlookup function. The syntax looks like this: VLOOKUP(lookup_value,table_array,col_index_num,range_lookup)

In this case, the lookup_value will be the first cell, the table array will be your original table (without the headers), the col_index_num will be 2 (which means it will take the answer from the second column), and range_lookup will be FALSE (which means it will look for an exact match)

If you want more information about either one of these steps, here's the official help sections for Excel 2010: [Create a drop down link](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/create-or-remove-a-drop-down-list-HP010342357.aspx) , [Vlookup](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/vlookup-function-HP010343011.aspx)